# MGWT ScrollPanel Snaping

Tags: mgwt

I am using the scrollpanel in mgwt to display images and i want it that when the user scrolls the closest image snaps to the top. i see there are two methods of the scrollpanel for snapping

```
void setSnap(boolean snap) 
void setSnapSelector(String selector)
```

I can't find any documentation on setSnapSelector. Can anyone tell me what this method does? And what it is supposed to be passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see an example of the snap selector in action take a look at the HeaderList widget: http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mgwt/ui/client/widget/HeaderList.java

If you enable snap and set a selector the scrollPanel will snap to a position after any touch. So if you have several images you want to pass img as a selector.